# Why are some blocks in gnuradio companion missing in raspbian, such as the Embedded Python Block?

Tags: raspbian, gnuradio-companion

I use GRC for signal processing. Some blocks are missing in the raspbian version. For example the Embedded Python Block is available in GRC windows, but in the raspbian version it is missing. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

Because the Version of GNU Radio orginally shipped with Raspbian is pretty outdated by now.